# How to use TextClassificationManager to Detect language

Tags: android, language-detection

`TextClassificationManager` is available from `API-26`. Its public methods available for classify text . 
My requirement is i need to detect language from a giver Text offline.
 `TextClassificationManager`  also have `detectLanguages()` method but its hidden.
Can i Use `TextClassificationManager` to detect language ?

I have searched a bit and i Found [This Project](https://github.com/JeppeLeth/android-languagedetection-study) Using `TextClassificationManager` by Reflection. But it throws `NoSuchMethodErrror` and Returns .. 
So if anyone Used `TextClassificationManager` for this purpose can help me .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bad decision to use hidden functions via reflection. You can never know if the function will be there and available so you have to prepare a fallback mechanism.

For Android SDK 26-27 You can try and use this Android lib project - https://github.com/rmtheis/language-detection but be aware that it's no longer maintained so use it for your own research but it's probably not a good idea to use it for production or apps released in Google Play.